# BorderBrush in C# XAMARIN.FORMS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to use `BorderBrush` in Xamarin Forms like we can do with WIN Phone XAML

```
 <Button Content="myButton" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="#FFFFFF" Background="#000000"/>
```

Is there a possibility to do it in `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: Have you tried `BorderColor`? ( https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderColor/ )

Comment: There are two questions here. Could you please split them into two questions. Not combined into one. You should know better. Also could you please do a little bit of research before asking, like taking a look at the api documentation. The label question is in the `Xamarin.Forms API documentation`

Comment: I split them. Thx for info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BorderBrush` in Xamarin.Forms is achievable through the `BorderColor` property. [Ref](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Button/)

So your button would be:

```
<Button Text="myButton" Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="#FFFFFF" BackgroundColor="#000000"/>
```